# Existe algum meio de entrar em contato direto com algum usuário?

Tags: suporte

Algumas horas tenho tido uns problemas nos scripts onde alguns usuários já obtiveram sucesso em consertar.

Queria saber se, ao invés de criar um post duplicada, há alguma maneira de entrar em contato com aquele usuário.

Comment: Você pode comentar abaixo do post, seja pergunta ou resposta, que o autor é notificado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, não há. O Stack Overflow não é uma rede social e não estimula a socialização.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma sala de bate papo (quando tiver a reputação para isso) e marcar o usuário no post que ele fez, indicando a existência da sala. No entanto, o sucesso disso vai depender muito da sua sorte. Muitos usuários de tempos atrás não estão mais ativos. Vários outros como eu são antissociais e não frequentam as salas de bate-papo.